# Substituting whole words only using Regex in Lua

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

I'm making a program that will correctly address the gender of the user. So it should replace every instance of `he` to `she` or vice versa.

The problem is this will also replace `he` inside words such as `them`, `their`, `help`...
This is where I'm stuck.

```
local str = "the he he's hell"

str = str:gsub("he", "she") --tried my best, not the correct solution!

print(str) --expecting "the she she's hell"
```

Basically replace all `he` to `she`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution that works both ways:

```
str = str:gsub("%a+", {he = "she", she = "he"})
```

`%a+` matches one or more letter which is basically word. that match is replaced by the respective table entry or stays unchanged.

There are other ways to to this but this is probably the shortest way to achieve a two-wway solution.

#### Edit:

> About the second param. I couldn't find any documentation about this.
> Do you have any?

Not sure where you've been looking for documentation but the [Lua Manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-string.gsub) says:

> **string.gsub (s, pattern, repl [, n])**
>
> ...
>
> If repl is a table, then the table is queried for every match, using
> the first capture as the key.

Comment: About the second param. I couldn't find any documentation about this. Do you have any?